# Convert ISO-8859-2 to UTF-8 (Polish characters)

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm trying to parse an XML file (http://jstryczek.blox.pl/rss2) that says its character set is ISO-8859-2. My database is in UTF-8, so I want to convert it to UTF-8.

To do that I run the following on the string:

```
$content = iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $content);
```

For some reason, I'm getting back an odd encoding, so that:

```
Gdzie są różnice
```

Comes through as:

```
Gdzie sÄ rĂłĹźnice
```

Is there an explanation for why the Polish characters aren't coming through? Does UTF-8 not support them?

Comment: UTF-8 support all Polish characters, I'm sure.

Comment: Which database do you use, how are the columns defined, how are you storing the text in the database, and how are you retrieving it? UTF-8 supports these characters just fine. In fact, the stackoverflow site is entirely in UTF-8, and as you can see you had no problems posting them.

Comment: I'm using MariaDB with the tables in UTF8, client connection is also UTF8. I think some sort of implicit conversion is happening somewhere, just not sure where.

Comment: Have you tried setting the connection character set to latin_2 and just sending the data as-is to the database? MySQL (and MariaDB I imagine) is able to translate between encodings from what the client sends to the encoding of the database/table. I've used this to translate UTF-8 to cp850 for correct display in Windows cmd before.

Comment: Turns out, that was the magic I needed to do. I had some code that would verify certain characters in UTF-8 that was messing up the conversion that was happening implicitly. I wrapped that in a check that verified the string was UTF-8 first, and my problems went away. I think either Curl, PHP, or MariaDB was doing an implicit conversion, and my explicit conversion was doubling it, causing the issues.

Answer (score 7):

I fix this by changing the string to JSON and then replace all polish special signs to HTML code. I add below my result:

```
        $specialChars = [
        '\u0105', # ą
        '\u0107', # ć
        '\u0119', # ę
        '\u0142', # ł
        '\u0144', # ń
        '\u00f3', # ó
        '\u015b', # ś
        '\u017a', # ź
        '\u017c', # ż
        '\u0104', # Ą
        '\u0106', # Ć
        '\u0118', # Ę
        '\u0141', # Ł
        '\u0143', # Ń
        '\u00d3', # Ó
        '\u015a', # Ś
        '\u0179', # Ż
        '\u017b', # Ż
    ];

    $polishHtmlCodes = [
        '&#261;', # ą
        '&#263;', # ć
        '&#281;', # ę
        '&#322;', # ł
        '&#324;', # ń
        '&#243;', # ó
        '&#347;', # ś
        '&#378;', # ź
        '&#380;', # ż
        '&#260;', # Ą
        '&#262;', # Ć
        '&#280;', # Ę
        '&#321;', # Ł
        '&#323;', # Ń
        '&#211;', # Ó
        '&#346;', # Ś
        '&#377;', # Ż
        '&#379;', # Ż
    ];

    $result = str_replace($specialChars, $polishHtmlCodes, json_encode($string));
    var_dump(json_decode($result));

// prints
// e.g. 'Różowe okulary'
```

Comment: What about html_entity_decode($string, null, 'utf-8') ?

Comment: There is a mistake in -> `'&#322;', # ń` should be -> `'&#324;', # ń`

Answer (score 3):

Seems, that this text is already encoded in utf-8, so there is no need to decode it. When I saved this file in utf-8 and ran it:

```
<?php
$content = 'Gdzie są różnice';
$content = iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $content);
print $content;
```

I got this:

```
Gdzie sÄ rĂłĹźnice
```

Which is exactly the incorrect text, you got.

Just save the text as is, it's already utf-8.

Comment: Then the server is reporting the wrong encoding, since it's coming through with Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-2. When I do nothing, I get either "?" or dropped characters for the non-ascii characters. Same if I just curl the url, I get "?" in a UTF8 console. Any thoughts?

Comment: @hukir Maybe, I was wrong and the encoding is really ISO-8859-2. Can you save the result of convertion to file and check it's encoding?

Comment: I used curl -O to save the file directly, and it saved with ISO-8859-1 with messed up characters. Leads me to believe it's a problem with the server I'm getting data from. Seems like it's a Windows server, which may be causing issues when my Ubuntu server fetches it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$content = 'Gdzie są różnice';
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, "ISO-8859-2", "UTF-8");
print $content;
?>
```